# array input never used

Tags: arrays, verilog

I'm trying to make a register array, and want to eliminate a warning.  I've created a minimal example design below.  Why is part of `addr` unused?

When I synthesize I get the warning:
`WARNING:Xst:647 - Input <addr<3:2>> is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.`

```
module test(addr,in,out,wr,clk);
input [3:0] addr;
input [7:0] in;
output reg [7:0] out;
input wr;
input clk;
reg [7:0] ra [0:3];

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (wr)
        ra[addr] = in;
    else
        out <= ra[addr];
end
endmodule
```

I'm trying to make a register that is 8 bits wide with 16 addresses (0-15).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following part of the given *warning* is important.

> Input "addr3:2" is never used.

Here, `addr` is four bits and `ra` is declared as `reg [7:0] ra [0:3];`. Assuming `ra` is termed as register-array (memory). This declares a memory of  ***4-byte***.

For addressing 4 bytes, only **two bits** are sufficient. So, the addresses goes as 00,01,10,11 only. The **upper bits** of `addr` are *never* used i.e. bits 3:2 are unused in any case. Hence the warning is issued.

For ***16-bytes*** of memory, you need to declare `ra` as `reg [7:0] ra [0:15];`, by this all the bits of `addr` shall be used up and warning should be removed.

Now for the second part of warning.

> This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.

Even though the bits are unused, they will be preserved by the synthesis tool and left unconnected. In case these lines are available in top-instantiating block. This is quite a reasonable thing to understand.

Comment: great explanation on the syntactic nuances.  it makes sense to me now that the count [0:15] is a count not addressing bits, though, I'm not sure why it confused me to begin with.

Comment: Any declaration of type `_packed_ **variable** _unpacked_` creates a two-dimensional memory. The unpacked side is the depth and packed side is for width of memory. Memories in verilog are explained better on [this](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00024.htm) link.